# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException on build, but works in Preview

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am referencing a library with a different assembly in a Xamarin.Forms app using Xaml in `Visual Studio Mac Preview`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns     ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x    ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RTE.Test.Forms"
    xmlns:rte="clr-namespace:RichTextEditor;assembly=RichTextEditor"
    x:Class    ="RTE.Test.Forms.RTE_Test_FormsPage">
    <rte:RichTextForm
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</ContentPage>
```

When I look at the iOS preview screen in VS, the `RichTextForm` renders perfectly. However, when I run the test on iOS simulator, I get the following error:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 8:3. Type rte:RichTextForm not found in xmlns clr-namespace:RichTextEditor;assembly=RichTextEditor

I have tried changing namespaces and assembly names, but since the Previewer can find the type just fine, I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Just looking at that and having similar situations in the past I would suggest that the RichTextEditor isn't available in the assembly used for iOS.  You may want to research it and make sure that control is available for that system.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII After more digging, I believe this is connected to the fact that the simulators/emulators (both iOS and Android) are not always updating to my newest code. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45327/newest-version-of-code-not-always-deployed-when-debugging-from-xamarin-studio#latest

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I've cleaned out everything and this bug continues.